# how to evalute expression values with parameter in postgres sql

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

I was trying to evaluate a regular expression in PostgreSQL in where clause.

I have a column with value like the example (1,2) below. When I write a query in where clause I am passing parameter values as either **"a"** or "a,b" or "b" then it should return only the rows that contain **"a"** or "a,b" or "b".

When I pass **"a"** then it should check the row value and evaluate the "AND" , "OR" conditions as well.

Example:1

```
((((a.b.city == "x" AND a.b.state == "y" AND a.b.country == "z")) OR 
   (dis(x.y.d1, x.y.d2, "47.6015", "-122.3304") <= 5)) 
  AND ((p.q.test == "**a**") OR (p.q.test == "b")))
```

Example:2

```
((((a.b.city == "x" AND a.b.state == "y" AND a.b.country == "z")) OR
   (dis(x.y.d1, x.y.d2, "123", "-456") <= 5)) AND ((p.q.test == "a,b")
```

Here is a sample query.

```
select * from testtable where  column ='parameter'
```

Please suggest.

Comment: For a question like this, a table of sample data and expected results makes things a lot easier to understand. So does cutting out unrelated noise in your queries. Please always supply your PostgreSQL version.

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to figure out quite what you're asking, but I *think* you want `IN(...)`.

E.g.

```
 p.q.test IN ('a', 'b')
```

is equivalent to

```
 p.q.test = 'a' OR p.q.test = 'b'
```

You can pass an array as a query parameter if the list to match is dynamic:

```
 p.q.test IN (?)
```

or a comma-separated list to match against:

```
 p.q.test = ANY (regexp_split_to_array(?,','))
```

If your `p.q.test` is a comma-separated value list, then split it, and compare it to an array of possible matches using the `&&` (array overlaps) operator:

```
WITH test(x) AS (VALUES ('a,b'), ('a'), ('b'), ('a,b,c'), ('b,c'), ('d,e'), ('e')) 
SELECT x, regexp_split_to_array(x, ',') && ARRAY['a','b'] FROM test;

   x   | ?column? 
-------+----------
 a,b   | t
 a     | t
 b     | t
 a,b,c | t
 b,c   | t
 d,e   | f
 e     | f
(7 rows)
```

If `&&` doesn't quite match what you want, look at the arrays manual; maybe the `@>` or `<@` (contains / contained by) operators are what you need.